# CSS Text Help for LayerSlider WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I'm very new to using css and need some help.

I'd like to add text to my homepage slider (I'm using LayerSlider WP) that looks like the text on a friend's website: brookefieldapartments.com

You can see that the text there is white on a transparent blue banner. I know he used css for that and created a class ID that he put into the Attributes section in LayerSlider.

My questions is, what would the css look like for me to have that kind of text and where would I need to place said css?

Thanks a lot!

Jon

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.80);
```

Change the first 3 values to the RGB values of your color, last value is opacity. Find the id or class names or slidername h3, then apply in your styles.css file.

Also the h2 or h3 or whatever should be:

```
display:inline-block;
padding:5px;
```

So the background doesn't go full width, and the padding allows some space between the text and the edge of the background.